# What is the command line argument for virtual enviroment paths?

Tags: python, python-venv

To run a certain script in crontab, I used to have `python3 /path/to/script` in my crontab entries.  This script requires one package from pip, the Python package manager.

Recent updates to Python [intentionally broke package management](https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/).  Now, packages must be managed manually:  you must designate packages in a "virtual environment", and then run Python under that virtual environment.

The current official [Python3 command line documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html) does not give any indication as to where this path should be put.  However, the official documentation is an undated document with no indication as to what version of Python this is current for.

What is the Python command line switch for virtual enviroment paths?

Comment: As far as I'm aware its not a switch you can use on the global/local installation, you'd use the python in the virtual environment to start the script instead.

eg: `source venv/bin/activate && python /path/to/script`

Comment: If you created the virtual environment, then you should know where it is. So what is the problem here?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

Answer (score 0):

> What is the Python command line switch for virtual enviroment paths?

There isn't one, as per the documentation you've read the virtual environment must be activated like so:

```
> source /path/to/venv/bin/activate
```

And normally you would be met with:

```
(venv) >
```

*Note the `(venv)` prefix specifying you are now in the virtual environment*

And from there you would install, run all your python 'needs'

As for running it from a single crontab command you should create a bash script that would activate the environment and then run your python file.

Hopefully that helps, feel free to read further here https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#create-and-use-virtual-environments
and here https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html (especially here for different systems/terminals)

Update 1:

> Here is an example bash script that crontab can run.

```bash
#! /bin/bash

cd /path/to/cwd

source /path/to/venv/bin/activate
python script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided you know the location of the virtual environment, all you need to do is use the `python3` executable from within that virtual environment, and it will be able to use any packages installed in that virtual environment without having to pre-activate the environment. E.g., say you created a virtual environment called `test`:

```bash
python3 -m venv test
```

and you activated that environment and installed, say, numpy:

```bash
source test/bin/activate
pip install numpy
```

Then, if you deactivate the environment:

```bash
deactivate
```

the Python executable from that environment can still see it's associated installed packages, e.g.:

```bash
test/bin/python3 -c "import numpy; print(numpy.__version__)"
```

will work.

So, in your crontab, just exchange:

```
python3 /path/to/script
```

for, e.g.,

```
test/bin/python3 /path/to/script
```

(you should probably use the full path to your virtual environment directory).